# Inserting one to one relationship is not working in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, laravel-5

I have two tables: client and payment_term. I want to save the client table while keeping a relationship with payment term.

My model classes are:

```
class Client extends Model {
    public function payment_term() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\PaymentTerm');
    }
}

class PaymentTerm extends Model {
    public function client() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\client');
    }
}
```

I need to insert client with payment.my code is given below but not working,

```
$client = new Client();
$client->name = Input::get('name');
$client->save();
//Payment term
$term = PaymentTerm::findOrFail(Input::get('term_id'));
$client->payment_term()->save($term);          
}
```

Could you help me to solve the issue? I have gone through docs and some others questions, but none of them are working for me. I also want to know the best practice for inserting a related model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are not setup correctly.  The complement to a `hasOne` relationship is a `belongsTo` relationship.  Additionally, it is the model that contains the foreign key field that is on the `belongsTo` side.

From the code, it looks to me like you have it setup so that the client table has a term_id field (the foreign key to the payment_term record).  If this is the case, your relationships should be:

```
class Client extends Model {
    public function payment_term() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\PaymentTerm', 'term_id');
    }
}

class PaymentTerm extends Model {
    public function client() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Client', 'term_id');
    }
}
```

You can find more on Laravel relationships in the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I think your $client->save() is causing the issue.

Try using this code instead -

```
$client = new Client();
$client->name = Input::get('name');
//Payment term
$term = PaymentTerm::findOrFail(Input::get('term_id'));
$term->client()->save($client);
```

Also you might need to change `App\Model\client` to `App\Model\Client`

About best practices I think the code examples on documentation could help you out - http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models